# How to use Database project in Application as reference

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, reference

I'm curios if you could add a reference to your project (CSharpApp) from an database project (TestDB) so that you are able to use here stored procedures.

**Exspection**:

```
using TestDB; // <- even if i add a reference i can't do this

namespace CSharpApp
{
    public class DBInteraction
    {
        public void CallProcedure()
        {
            using(SqlConnection conn = doMagic())
            {
                //or something similar
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(TestDB.MyProcedureName.Tostring(),conn))
                {
                    // duStoff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wasn't able to find anything about that on the internet. Anything hint to this topic is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

### Update:

The `using` will throw  "*type or namespace could not be found*".

**Is there a way to achieve what i was expecting in some way?**

Comment: I don't get your question. Are you asking how to add a project reference?

Comment: @PatrickHofman i know how to add a reference to an other project, but if you create a DB project and an C# project and you add a reference from your DB project to your C# project you can't use `using` to access his "classes" in my case stored procedures, because the `using` as is self will throw an error

Comment: What classes? Is a DB project not a *DB* project? There is no code, right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman right, there is no code because it is an sqlproject, but i thought visualstudio will let me access atleaste the names.

Comment: What names do you mean?

Comment: @PatrickHofman names of my table, stored procedures, maybe even from my fields

Comment: How? How should the database project know all this, and what namespace and class names to use?

Comment: @PatrickHofman the name of the project is as fare is i know the default namespace in the project and the project contains all (tables,stored procedures, ...) so it would be possible if they had add such a feature.

Comment: I guess there isn't. You can create your own though.